# Matlab: selected values of spectrogram

Tags: matlab, frequency, spectrogram

I have calculated the spectrogram of a file .wav using the code reported here:

https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Matlab_listing_myspectrogram_m.html

Now, I want select elements of this spectrogram under a determinated threshould of frequency. 
How can I calculated these values?

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
B = myspectrogram(x,nfft,fs,window,noverlap,doplot,dbdown);
```

and set a threshold on frequency:

```
inds = find(Fs<threshold);
```

then the new frequencies and the relative portion of the spectrogram are:

```
newfreq = Fs(inds);
spect = B(inds);
```